# "error: file not specified" while importing XML file through maximo integration framework with XSLT in enterprise service

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, maximo

I'm working on XSLT in maximo.
I have written an XSLT for mapping external field name with maximo fields for invbalances. I have given the path of XSLT file (`C:\mif\schema\external\sampleinv4.xsl`) in enterprise service.

When I try to import an XML file I am getting the error

> BMXAA4214E - An unknown error has occurred.
>   Please contact your system administrator for assistance.
>   Gather the logs from the  directory and determine where and why the error is thrown.
>       com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException:
>   C:\mif\schema\external\sampleinv4.xsl (The system cannot find the file specified.)

but the file is specified in correct path.
**XSLT file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:maximoMappings="local" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SyncTESTALCONINVBALANCE xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
            <TESTALCONINVBALANCESet>
                <INVBALANCES>
                    <SITEID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="SITEID"/>
                    </SITEID>
                    <ITEMNUM>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ITEMNUM"/>
                    </ITEMNUM>
                    <ITEMSETID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ITEMSETID"/>
                    </ITEMSETID>
                    <LOCATION>
                        <xsl:value-of select="LOCATION"/>
                    </LOCATION>
                    <BINNUM>
                        <xsl:value-of select="BINNUM"/>
                    </BINNUM>
                    <CURBAL>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ONHANDBAL"/>
                    </CURBAL>
                </INVBALANCES>
            </TESTALCONINVBALANCESet>
        </SyncTESTALCONINVBALANCE>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`
**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncTESTALCONINVBALANCE xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" 
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  creationDateTime="2017-03-22T18:37:26+05:30" transLanguage="EN"  baseLanguage="EN" messageID="7798510.1490188046810982972"  maximoVersion="7 6 20141117-2230 V7600-218" event="0">
    <TESTALCONINVBALANCESet>
        <INVBALANCES>
            <SITEID>FLEET</SITEID>
            <ITEMNUM>11R22.5GS-16</ITEMNUM>
            <ITEMSETID>SET1</ITEMSETID>
            <LOCATION>DALLAS</LOCATION>
            <BINNUM />
            <ONHANDBAL>16.0</ONHANDBAL>
        </INVBALANCES>
    </TESTALCONINVBALANCESet>
</SyncTESTALCONINVBALANCE>
```

Comment: I improved code formatting, some spelling and added two relevant tags.

Comment: I'm not familiar with maximo, but maybe it's having an issue with the Windows path. Have you tried setting the path to `C:/mif/schema/external/sampleinv4.xsl`? Or if it needs a URI `file:///C:/mif/schema/external/sampleinv4.xsl`?

Comment: tried with both. But no use.

Comment: 2) Have you tried MxLoader to create your files? I'm under the impression XSLT is not required. The Maximo Object Structure `TESTALCONINVBALANCE` contains the objects and attributes information. 2) Sorry, I have to ask the dumb question... Is the XSLT on your computer, or on the server that WebSphere/WebLogic is installed on?

Answer (score 0):

File name in XSLT path and filename in Error message seems to be different. After adding new XSLT please try restarting the app server.

Comment: Different file name given was by mistake. Even after restarting the appserver also its giving same error